# Does ProGuard protect data in source code?

Tags: android, security, encryption, proguard

I am currently writing an Android library (AAR file) that will ship with a database (to be put in the asset/ folder of the app). The data in the database includes some sensitive data that I'd like to protect from the users of my library and database.

I've thought about encrypting the data and storing the decryption key in my library's source code. But of course this method is super unsafe, as anyone can decompile the source code and read the decryption key.

Then my colleague suggested doing the above and using ProGuard to obfuscate the source code, making it unintelligible for the decompiler to understand what and where the key is. Could this method work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Proguard` will obfuscate the code by giving random meaningless names to all method, classes and variables. Even of decompiled these are hard to understand without the `mappings.txt` file which will be only with you. Keep it safe for troubleshooting issues in production.

But the **hard coded strings will still be seen when decompiled**. You need to manipulate the string and store it as encrypted or something. Write a method to decrypt it before using.

Read more about proguard and it's advantages [here](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks for explaining what ProGuard does. As for your suggestion of encrypting the key, then how do I decrypt the key? I would need to hardcode the key to decrypt the key, right? And now we're back at square one :( I guess there's no way to protect the data then?

Comment: No not that way. Just use some combinations of split reverse etc so that the string is stored differently. Patch it up together before use. Do this only for sensitive information like keys etc. Not everything

Answer (score 1):

No it will not protect your data (String literals, hard coded values etc). It will only obfuscate your code.

For storing cryptographic keys (in ur case your decryption key), [KeyStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html/) can be used.